# The problem about paging after sorting a specific column in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I met a problem about paging after sorting a specific column in mysql.
I cannot get the right results for page 2 by DESC sorting, but I can get right by id column.... I'm puzzled. Will it be caused by null/blank value?

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/q8hsPchRT4hg67pssfoz48/3

any suggestion?
great thx.

Comment: I don't understand what you think is wrong here. But here's an example of why I don't like to use strings as ids.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have to say once you wanna to use below sql to paging, you must make sure, the column has individual value. blank and null value will caused wrong paging results.

```
SELECT a.* 
  FROM tbl a 
  WHERE a.id <=
       (SELECT id 
          FROM tbl ORDER BY id desc LIMIT 10,1 )  
         ORDER BY a.id desc LIMIT 10
```